# Where to add Http Response Header in code?

Tags: html, cors

I am still learning api calls, and currently receive an error regarding Cross Origin Resource Sharing - from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

to my vague understanding, this may be resolved by with "Http Response Header" 
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://example.com:8080

I am not quite sure how to do this.

with my current javascript being

```
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      myFunction(this);
    }
  };
 xhttp.open("GET", "https://otherexample.com/", true);
  xhttp.setRequestHeader('Authorization','Basic Yhtghufhilahliviemiufhiaowi87975 ==');
   xhttp.send();
}
```

would my new code be

```
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      myFunction(this);
    }
  };
 xhttp.open("GET", "https://otherexample.com/", true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','http:example.com:8080')
  xhttp.setRequestHeader('Authorization','Basic Yhtghufhilahliviemiufhiaowi87975 ==');
   xhttp.send();
}
```

i have tried this but doesn't seem to work.

Comment: This is generally a server issue, with the server saying "I don't take data from there."  Look up what pre-flight is, then look up what CORS is.  It'll make sense from there.

Comment: Do you control otherexample.com?

Comment: i do not control otherexample.com

Comment: with all due respect, i looked through the example that this was marked as duplicate of, and still don quite understand